# Reading special Charanters in XML org.w3c.dom

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, w3c

I´m reading a XML with characters like "ñ". When i use

```
...
Node c = nodeList.item( j);
c.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
...
```

for to read this

```
<ID>1Ññ</ID>
```

I get:

```
1Ã‘Ã±
```

Any idea?

The xml file starts with the following line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your character encoding.

The character sequence `Ã‘Ã±` clearly shows that there are UTF-8 characters that are decoded in any other character encoding (presumbly ISO-8859-1).

Please check your complete application that the encodings are correct.

Start with the method `parse()` in the `DocumentBuilder` and use the method that uses a `InputSource` and create the `InputSource` with a `Reader` that has the correct encoding (ISO-8859-1 in you case).

Comment: All it´s ok, the problem was in other place of my program. I was reading a file in incorrect codepage.
Thank you for your response.